# How to get some xml data from a huge sql file?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

My sql file is 2.4 gigabyte with more than 100000 insert commands. With mmap I can extract 1000 opendata datasets in 2 minutes.

Some regex matches cover more than one insert command! How can I avoid this?

Code I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

regex = r'''<thing(.*?\r?\n)+?.*?<bbb(.*?\r?\n)+?.*?<three[^\r\n]+opendata(.*?\r?\n)+?.*?</thing.*?>'''

input_string = r'''
INSERT INTO blah...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>beer</three>
</bbb>
</thing>

INSERT INTO blah...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>opendata</three>
</bbb>
</thing>

INSERT INTO blah...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>opendata2</three>
</bbb>
</thing>
'''

items = re.finditer(regex, input_string, re.I)

for item in items:
    print 'Start...'
    print item.group(0)
    print '...end'
    print
```

Output:

```
Start...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>beer</three>
</bbb>
</thing>

INSERT INTO blah...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>opendata</three>
</bbb>
</thing>
...end

Start...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>opendata2</three>
</bbb>
</thing>
...end
```

What I want:

```
Start...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>opendata</three>
</bbb>
</thing>
...end

Start...
<thing>
<bbb>
<three>opendata2</three>
</bbb>
</thing>
...end
```

Comment: You really should not be doing *any* work on XML files with regular expressions.

Comment: Than I have to insert all data into database which takes much longer?

Comment: No, I'd suggest you read up on SAX parsers (like [the one in `lxml`](http://lxml.de/sax.html)) and base your approach on that.

Comment: But sql syntax is not xml syntax; works anyway?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, sorry. You're right, if it's not an XML file an XML parser will not help.

Comment: No prob. Maybe (?<!\</thing) will help but I do not know where to add.

Comment: I'm thinking. You still could *make* it an XML file. If it looks like the sample you posted, all that's missing is an initial opening tag (and a closing tag at the end). You'd get a huge XML file with some irrelevant SQL sprinkled between the parts that interest you, which you could then feed to a streaming parser. For a one-off solution you could of course also `re.split()` on `^INSERT.*` and deal with the parts you get this way. I'd still dis-recommend trying to parse out the XML snippets themselves with regular expressions.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do; because the title of your post is not a question, and I am not sure what you want to extract or skip or what. You want to remove anything that has beer in it?

Comment: I have a sql file with lots of beer and other stuff in it and I only want the opendata inserts. Doing it the normal way (like insert into database) takes longer than extracting the opendata with regex. I now try `re.split()`.